# Rest API with Jersey: What am I missing?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I have a working servlet maven project that I wanted to extend with a Rest API based on Jersey.

I have created a basic API class like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/api")
public class CheckHaveIBeenPwned {

    @GET
    @Produces( "text/html;charset=UTF-8" )
    public String whatever() {
        return "Hallo";
    }

}
```

In pom.xml I included the following jersey dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My web.xml (essentially) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExistingServletClass</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.whatever.servlet.ExistingServletClass</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <!-- a few more (still working) servlet sections -->
  <servlet>
      <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
      <servlet-name>REST-Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>REST-Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExistingServletClass</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/existingservletclass</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <-- a few more (still working) servlet mappings -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

But when I try to call the API (simply by opening the following URL in the browser):

https://my.url:8443/myapp/rest/api

I only get a 404 "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." whereas the "normal" application with the other servlets still works like this

https://my.url:8443/myapp

What am I missing? I did a very similar thing in another project and it worked. But adding the Rest API to this existing project keeps failing ...

Comment: Do you have an `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class?

Comment: I don't understand ...

Comment: Check this: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e10980

Comment: I don't know how this could match my project ... I did the exact same thing in another project, without any Application setting

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to change pom.xml to include jersey-bundle (no idea why, but now it works):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It's really strange ... but I am satisfied now